# Access to an external API using salesforce?

Tags: api

I am trying to implement an API that will connect to an external database or software to get relevant informations. Can you please give me some ideas about how to start and how to do ?

EX:

1 - mySalesForceAPI  --(connect to) -> external source

2 - external source --(sends info) -> mySalesForce DB

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the REST API and the SOAP API. These would be the relevant docs: [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) and [SOAP API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/). Also refer to the [Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/). Which to use will depend a lot on what works best on the other end. Salesforce supports both very well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also looking for REST API but I have another question, can I send any data from SF to any database ?

Comment: Yes, you can export data. Take a look at Data Loader for exports. You can also create classes to do it real time in streaming data mode or in scheduled batches. Depends a lot on your use case. Be aware that you do need to consider API usage limits when you start doing those kinds of things using streaming or scheduling.

Comment: You mean by code or any executable ? Because the way I want is more with using the code. I want to get all datas from SF and send it to my database without using any executable

Comment: A class would run as code in Salesforce. An executable would run from your desktop. Batch processes can be scheduled in Salesforce from classes. There are many ways to accomplishing data transfers depending on their urgency. For back-ups, the streaming API would not be a good use of your limits on API calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, they helped me so much. I ve just last question, can you please give me a link or explane how to run a code in Salesforce like you have told on your last comment?

Comment: Look inside the Apex Code Developer's Guide at these two links: [Apex Scheduler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) and [Using Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) as starting points (assumes a knowledge of Classes).